# Line integral of complex expression

Tags: complex-integration

How can we integrate expressions like these $\int_C \operatorname{Re}(Z) \, dZ$ where $C$ is the  shortest path joining the points $1+i$ and $3+2i$.

The $\operatorname{Re}(Z)$ in the expression is what confusing me.

Comment: Don't you know what $\Re(z)$ is?

Comment: Real part of Z .

Comment: Do you know that given a path $\gamma \colon [a,b]\to \mathbb C$, then $\int _\gamma f(z)\mathrm dz=\int \limits_a^b f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)\mathrm dt$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{Z = 1 + \ic + \pars{2 + \ic}\mu\quad}$ with $\ds{\quad 0 \leq \mu \leq 1}$.
\begin{align}
\color{#00f}{\large\int_{C}\Re\pars{Z}\,\dd Z}&=
\int_{0}^{1}\pars{1 + 2\mu}\,\bracks{\pars{2 + \ic}\,\dd\mu}
=\pars{2 + \ic}\int_{0}^{1}\pars{1 + 2\mu}\,\dd\mu
=\left.\pars{2 + \ic}\pars{\mu + \mu^{2}}\right\vert_{0}^{1}
\\[3mm]&=\color{#00f}{\large 4 + 2\ic}
\end{align}

Comment: how did you find $\ds{Z = 1 + \ic + \pars{2 + \ic}\mu\quad}$

Comment: @user2332665 This is the expression for a line segment which start at $\large 1 + {\rm i}$ (when $\large\mu = 0$) and end at $\large 3 + 2{\rm i}$ (when $\large\mu = 1$).

Answer (score 1):

As $t$ goes from $0$ to $1$, then $(1-t)(1+i) + t(3+2i)$ goes from $1+i$ to $3+2i$ along a straight line.  So let $z=x+iy=(1-t)(1+i) + t(3+2i)$, so that $\operatorname{Re}(z) = x$.  Then
$$
\int_C \operatorname{Re}(z)\,dz = \int_{t=0}^{t=1} x\, (dx+i\,dy) = \int_0^1 ((1-t)(1)+t(3)) \, (2\,dt + i\,dt)
$$
$$
=\int_0^1 ((1-t)(1)+t(3))\, 2\,dt + i\int_0^1 ((1-t)(1)+t(3))\,dt.
$$

Comment: i can't understand how did you parameterised to $(1−t)(1+i)+t(3+2i)$. If it was Z instead of Re(Z) i would find the equation of the line, which is $x+2y=3$ and substitute $x=3-2y$ in $x+iy$ and put $dZ=-2dy+idy$ then integrate over y = 1 to 2 . could you explain your method

Comment: As $t$ goes from $0$ to $1$, then $(1-t)A+tB$ goes from $A$ to $B$ along a straight line.  That's true of any two points $A$ and $B$ in Euclidean space, or more generally in convex spaces.  One way to look at it is this: We want to start at $A$ when $t=0$ and end at $B$ when $t=1$, so we start at $A$ and ultimately add $B-A$ to that, getting $A + (B-A)$, which is of course $B$.  But how much of $B-A$ do we add?  It depends on how far we've progressed along the path.  When we're one-third of the way from $A$ to $B$, then we add only $1/3$ of $B-A$, etc.  When we're $100\cdot t\%$ there, then...

Comment: ...then we add $t(B-A)$ to our starting point $A$, getting $A\  +\  t(B-A)$, which simplifies to $(1-t)A+tB$.  When we're one-third of the way along the path from $A$ to $B$, our position is $2/3$ of $A$ plus $1/3$ of $B$, i.e. $(2/3)A+(1/3)B$, and similarly for other fractions.  I.e.  $(1-t)A+tB$.